# Cannot compile tarball

Tags: configuration, software-installation

I have a tarball, gimp-2.6.6.tar.bz2, and I extracted it to

`/usr/local/src/gimp-2.6.6`

then did

`cd /usr/local/src/gimp-2.6.6`

Next I did

`./configure`

It put all that stuff into terminal, but stopped at

`checking for BABL:`

and failed, saying it couldn't find BABL.  A few sources said to do

`sudo apt-get install libbabl-dev`

so I did and it worked.  However, it then got stuck on

`checking for GEGL:`

and failed again, saying it couldn't find GEGL.  I tried

`sudo apt-get install libgegl-dev`

and it downloaded and installed it, but it still did not configure. So I tried

`sudo apt-get install gegl*`

but it still didn't configure.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you following command than yours.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gimp
```

Ubuntu repository has also gimp source.

Although repository's gimp version is not same gimp tarball, it's build dependencies is almost same.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work.